# A crossword with no clues?

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, rebus, crosswords

This crossword doesn't appear to have any clues... or does it?

---

[image: Crossword]

---

#### **Solve the crossword to get a bonus puzzle, and find the final word to describe the crossword!**

<sub>[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18ICT14zMuXB8q7n8gPj0RulG0V6S4wNHfLccZA3ODzQ/edit?usp=sharing)</sub>

Comment: Have I been one-upped? hahaha :)

Comment: @JLee I actually did get inspiration for this from your get-a-clue one, been trying to solve it and just gave me an idea for this :P

Comment: i got the blue letters, but still thinking

Comment: Are those black bars word dividers or just an image artifact?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore hmm I don't see any black bars other than the individual box borders? There's no word dividers if that helps, each line should be the same

Comment: Must be my screen resolution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The crossword is solved like this

> [image]

Props to @Ankoganit for solving the rebus, because I stared at it for 30 minutes.

> **ECONTAD**, or, in other words, CONTA in ED --> **CONTAINED**

Comment: Not quite!! I'll give you a hint for the very last quick step - I've added the [tag:rebus] ;)

Comment: wait, duh, I need to find a word! I forgot, and I am the one who suggested the word tag. geesh!

Comment: I think to the solution to the rebus must be (rot13) PBAGN va RQ, v.r., PBAGNVARQ.

Comment: @Ankoganit yep correct!